# How to retrieve won or lost data from previous period?

Tags: sql, time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have contract table with the following values:

| Period | Region | Entity | Tag | Ref | Program | User | EndUser | Date Begin | Date End | Period M-1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-01 | NA | US | tag1 | DK80 | Program1 | User1 | EndUser | 2018-07-13 | 2019-03-05 | 2018-07-01 |
| 2018-09-01 | NA | US | tag1 | WXD | Program1 | User2 | EndUser1 | 2018-07-13 | 2019-03-05 | 2018-08-01 |
| 2018-10-01 | NA | US | tag1 | MDK45 | Program2 | User3 | EndUser2 | 2018-07-13 | 2019-03-05 | 2018-09-01 |
| 2018-11-01 | NA | US | tag1 | CX49 | Program3 | User4 | EndUser3 | 2018-07-13 | 2019-03-05 | 2018-10-01 |

My question is quite simple but the answer is more harder than expected for me.
How retrieve efficiently the won & lost users for each period based on (Period M-1)?

They should have the same (Region,Entity,Tag,Ref,Program,User,EndUser,Date Begin,Date End).

**Update:**

Could you please validate those results as it seems right now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST (
    Period  TIMESTAMP,
    PeriodM1 TIMESTAMP,
    ID      VARCHAR,
    Tag     VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO TMP_TEST 
VALUES 
('2020-10-01','2020-09-01',  'ID1',  'A'),
('2020-11-01','2020-10-01',  'ID2',  'A'),
('2020-12-01','2020-11-01',  'ID2',  'A'),
('2021-01-01','2020-12-01',  'ID3',  'A'),
('2020-10-01','2020-09-01',  'ID1',  'X'),
('2020-11-01','2020-10-01',  'ID2',  'X'),
('2020-12-01','2020-11-01',  'ID3',  'X'),
('2021-01-01','2020-12-01',  'ID3',  'X');

--Won
SELECT A.* 
FROM TMP_TEST A
WHERE
A.ID NOT IN (SELECT B.ID FROM TMP_TEST B WHERE B.Period = A.PeriodM1 )

--Lost
SELECT A.Period,B.Period,B.ID,B.Tag
FROM TMP_TEST A, TMP_TEST B
WHERE B.Period = A.PeriodM1
AND A.ID NOT IN (B.ID)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;

-- Won and Lost
SELECT A.*, 1 AS WON,0 AS LOST
FROM TMP_TEST A
WHERE
A.ID NOT IN (SELECT B.ID FROM TMP_TEST B WHERE B.Period = A.PeriodM1 )
UNION
SELECT A.Period,B.Period,B.ID,B.Tag,0 AS WON,1 AS LOST
FROM TMP_TEST A, TMP_TEST B
WHERE B.Period = A.PeriodM1
AND A.ID NOT IN (B.ID)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

Answer (score 2):

The basics would be a `lag() over()`, but you still need to define each period's metrics:

```sql
select lag(metric) over(
  partition by Region,Entity,Tag,Ref,Program,User,EndUser,DateBegin,DateEnd 
  order by period
)
from (select your_period_metrics)
```